# Can you create a check_box_tag inside javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

The way that elements are being created on the view is mainly through JavaScript. I'd like to be able to add a check_box_tag dynamically alongside a list item that is also created dynamically so that I can access the checkboxes in params.

There is a haml file that is rendered alongside the JavaScript files, so I created a javascript function and called this in the JavaScript file that creates the rest of the elements.

Script inside JS file:

```
$(options).each(function()
        {
          genCheckbox();
          $('#unorderedRight').append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '" style="display:inline;" title="'+ $(this).text()+'" onclick="selectLi(this)" selected=false>'+$(this).text()+'</li><br id="'+ $(this).text()+'_br">');
}
```

Script inside haml file:

```
%script#genCheckbox
  :plain
    function genCheckbox()
    {
      $("#unorderedRight").append("=check_box_tag 'someid', 'somename', false ");
    }
```

The expected result is that a checkbox appears alongside the list item. It is instead showing "=check_box_tag 'someid', 'somename', false"

Comment: `check_box_tag` is server-side concept. So is HAML. They don't exist in javascript. Do it similarly to how you do in your other JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your HTML string with the following:

```js
$('#unorderedRight').append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '" style="display:inline;" title="'+ $(this).text()+'" onclick="selectLi(this)" selected=false><input type="checkbox" name="'+ $(this).text()+'" value="'+ $(this).text()+'" /> '+$(this).text()+'</li><br id="'+ $(this).text()+'_br">');
```

Comment: Creating a checkbox like this does not enable me to catch the value of it in rails params though, does it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I thought I had, however I did not specify the 'value' attribute. The params list now contains the checkboxes that had been checked only.

Comment: @StefanN Is there a way to make the default value of the checkbox blank, or false? I need a way to require the params for the checkboxes inside of my join table model.

Comment: just add `checked="false"` to the checkbox element ==> `<input type="checkbox" checked="false" />`

Comment: This seems to check the checkbox by default. When I uncheck it, it is not stored in params.